# Reduced homology of $S^n - i(I^k)$ is trivial

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $0\leq k \leq n$ and $i:I^k\rightarrow S^n$ embedding. Show that $$\tilde{H_*}(S^n-i(I^k))=0. $$

I started by induction on $k$ and wrote $I^k$ as union of two cuboids $K_1$ and $K_2$, for which $K_1\cap K_2 = I^{k-1}\times\{\dfrac{1}{2}\}$. Then $S^n-i(I^k)=(S^n-i(K_1))\cap (S^n-i(K_2))$

Set $A=S^n-i(K_1)$, $B=S^n-i(K_2)$, $X^k=A\cap B$ and $X^{k-1}=A\cup B$. Mayer-Vietoris sequence is:
$$\dots \rightarrow H_{n-1}(X^{k-1})\rightarrow H_n(X^k)\rightarrow H_n(S^n-i(I^{k-1}))\bigoplus H_n(S^n-i(I^{k-1}))\rightarrow H_n(X^{k-1})\rightarrow \dots$$
$X^0$ is contractible, $H_*(X^{k-1})=0$ by induction hypothesis, $S^n-i(I^{k-1})\simeq X^{k-1}$ so $H_n(X^k)=0$. Have I missed anything?

Comment: What tools do you have available? This is a very simple application of Alexander Duality, but you also have a nice setup for Mayer-Vietoris because $(S^n - i(K_1)) \cup (S^n - i(K_2)) = S^n - i(K_1\cap K_2)$. (I think it should also be possible to show directly that $S^n - i(I^k)$ is contractible, be this might have technical difficulties.)